# Run multiple sails apps behind single port

Tags: node.js, deployment, sails.js, server

I'm a noob at sails and only been using for a couple of days. 
I'm accustomed to Spring MVC, where you can run multiple apps behind a single port, with each app having it's own context.

For example:

serverip:8080/app1
serverip:8080/app2
serverip:8080/app3
...

Is this possible with sails/node.js?
Excuse my noobness but could't find an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a reverse proxy. There are some [node modules](http://blog.ccare.me/blog/2013/09/18/custom-reverse-proxying-with-node-dot-js) for that. But if you really need this I'd advice to setup nginx as a reverse proxy on your server.

Comment: Yes, I know a reverse proxy or mod_jk to connect to apache/nginx.
My real doubt is: right know I'm running a app at the base context: localhost:1337. How can multiple apps be ran at the same port, but with diffenret contexts like the example I posted above?
I'm asking this because I'll need to run sails behind apache with some kind of mod_jk because I only have one externally acessible port: port 80.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to run multiple sails apps but afraid that it can use only the 1337 port or you don't want to bother with apache configs and provide one node app that runs on one port and manages other apps?

Comment: Ok, sorry it I wasn't clearer.
My current setup is apache as a load balancer with tomcat behind it using mod_jk.
I'm trying to switch from Java EE to node.js.
What I want is to keep apache as a balancer(cant really change it, already have dependencies) and run sails behind it, on a single port (1337 for example). However, I want to run multiple apps on port 1337 which, from my experience, requires that each apps runs in its own context.
My idea is that the apps mappings would look like so (dont really know if I'm correct on this):
serverip:1337/app1 , serverip:1337/app2 , serverip:1337/app3,..

Comment: So the solution that I know of, is to run thous apps in different ports and use a reverse proxy in the middle running on port 1337 which than will translate to other apps. Like that:
apache:80 -> middle-reverse-proxy:1337
middle-reverse-proxy:1337/app1 -> app1:1338
middle-reverse-proxy:1337/app2 -> app2:1339
you can use eather another apache/nginx for that or https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy. If you have access to the original apache, you can configure it directly

Comment: Ok, not exactly what I was looking for but thanks for your help!